# Use rules of inference to show that if ∀x(P (x) → Q(x)), ∀x(Q(x) → R(x)), and ∃x(¬R(x)) are true, then ∃x(¬P(x)) is true.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

i'm not sure what I'm being asked to do. Should i prove them separately? an example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show that the first two statements are equivalent to $\forall x\ P(x)\Rightarrow R(x)$. Then what is the relation between this and the third statement?

Comment: Formally, the problem is: $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)), \forall x (Q(x) \rightarrow R(x)), \exists x (\lnot R(x)) \vdash \exists x (\lnot P(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

```
01 ∀x[P(x)→Q(x)]    premise
02 ∀x[Q(x)→R(x)]    premise
03 ∃x[¬R(x)]        premise
  04 ¬R(a)          assumption
    05 P(a)         assumption
    06 P(a)→Q(a)    ∀elim 01 a/x
    07 Q(a)         MP 06 05
    08 Q(a)→R(a)    ∀elim 02 a/x
    09 R(a)         MP 08 07
    10 ⊥            contradiction 09 04
  11 ¬P(a)          ¬intro 05-10
  12 ∃x[¬P(x)]      ∃intro 11 a/x
13 ∃x[¬P(x)]        ∃elim 03 04-12
```